# WHMCS - Catch SQL errors

Tags: php, sql, whmcs

I am using WHMCS for managing the members of my website, and I am facing a problem with my sql queries.

Here is the logic of the code :

```
while(!$boolean && tries<10){
... CODE...
if($count==0)
{
    $table = "name_of_table";
    $value = array("field"=>"value", ...);
    $newid = insert_query($table,$values);
    $boolean = true;
    break;
}
tries++;
}
if($boolean){
    $table = "other_table";
    $value = array("field"=>"value", ...);
    $newid = insert_query($table,$values);
}
```

The problem is that the second query does not run.

I did a few verifications : the programs goes into the if(boolean) condition, but the insert_query inside of it returns the id.... of the previous query (the one in the loop) !

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here ?

Comment: Try to change variable $newid in if($boolean) statement and check.

Comment: I found the error which was an sql error. The question is : how to show the sql errors with whmcs ? (sorry if that was not clear)